# How can Wien's Displacement Law be 'changed' to a version for frequency?

Tags: thermodynamics, frequency, blackbody

[Wien's Displacement Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien's_displacement_law) stated that for a blackbody emitting radiation,

$$\lambda_{max}=\dfrac{1}{T}$$

where $T$ is the temperature of the body and $\lambda_{max}$ is the maximum wavelength of radiation emitted.

Due to the relationship between wavelength, frequency and the speed of light, a value of maximum wavelength would give a value of minimum frequency, and vice versa.

I then saw on the Wikipedia page for [Wien's Displacement Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien's_displacement_law#Frequency-dependent_formulation) that

$$f_{max}=\dfrac{\alpha k_BT}{h},$$

where $\alpha=2.82...$, $k_B$ is Boltzmann's Constant, $T$ is the temperature of the body and $h$ is Planck's Constant.

How can this relationship for maximum frequency be shown?

Comment: You've misstated Wien's law. There is no maximum wavelength - the possible wavelengths in the thermal radiation span interval from $0$ to $\infty$. The meaning of $\lambda_m$ in the Wien law is that it gives wavelength at which the spectral distribution function $I(\lambda,T)$ is maximum.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I misread the question. In light of what @JánLalinský pointed out I retract my previous comment. (P.S. Jan you might consider posting that as an answer)

Comment: @DavidZ the question is misconcepted, so I prefer to just comment and give some time to questioner to consider rewriting it.

Comment: OK that makes sense, I'm in my first month of university so perhaps some explanations are simplified at this level and then become more technical as the course progresses.

Answer (score 1):

The Wien displacement law gives the [maximum of a function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima#Finding_functional_maxima_and_minima), so the way to compute it is to start with the Planck function in frequency domain,
$$
B(\nu,T)=\frac{8\pi\nu^2}{c^3}\frac{h\nu}{e^{h\nu/kT}-1}
$$
Take the derivative with respect to $\nu$, set it equal to zero and solve for $\nu$. You'll likely have to use some numerical methods (e.g., [iterative searching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)) to find the value.